# Is our Beta label being removed?

Tags: discussion

Since we learned that [Matter Modeling is graduating](https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/298/5) and [Quantum Computing is graduating](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/517/2293), I'm curious if Drones will be too?

Comment: I'm not sure if these kinds of things are covered under our NDAs, either explicitly or by professional convention (*idk what to call it*), so IDK if us mods can comment on the record here about this topic. Since you're also an SE mod, we can likely talk in a sidebar...

Answer (score 3):

Well, it just did as of this past morning (*12/16/21*). One of the SE community managers clarified to us (*site moderators*) that they felt we were ready to graduate even though we haven't met all of the requirements usually used to gauge beta site progress.

That said, the credit for this milestone is really attributable to all of us in the Drones.SE community, posting and answering questions. Thank you all for helping us grow the site, but more importantly, spread knowledge about model/scale aviation!

Comment: Cheers to everyone who helped bring this site to where it is today!